# Using a while loop to loop over an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

I'm going through bootcamp lab and facing some challenge in a looping lab. The exercise asks to create a function which accepts one argument - an array of facts. I have to use a while loop to loop over the facts array, add `!!!` to the end of every fact, and return an array of strings with exclamation points.

```js
const facts = [
  "He was the last Beatle to learn to drive",
  "He was never a vegetarian",
  "He was a choir boy and boy scout",
  "He hated the sound of his own voice"
];

function johnLennonFacts() {
  let i = 0;
  while (i <= facts.lenght) {
    i++;
    console.log(facts[i] + '!!!');
  }
  return facts
}
```

Comment: Hey, you mistyped `facts.length` first of all

Comment: 1) your function doesn't accept an argument, 2) you misspelled `length`, 3) wait to increment `i` until _after_ you access `facts[i]`

Comment: does it have to use a `while` loop?

Comment: Please show your exception or log outputs when posting questions so that we can see the direct errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comments in the code :

```js
const data = [
  "He was the last Beatle to learn to drive",
  "He was never a vegetarian",
  "He was a choir boy and boy scout",
  "He hated the sound of his own voice"
];

function johnLennonFacts(facts) {
//                       ^^^^^
// your function has to accept the argument here

  var data = facts.slice(); // make a copy of the passed array
  
  var i = 0;

  while (i < data.length) { // fix misspelled length

    data[i] += '!!!'; // use += to add the !!!
    
    i++; // increment after adding the !!!
  }

  return data
}

var result = johnLennonFacts(data); // call the function 
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Please fix notice that it mutates the original array `data`

Comment: @MaheerAli , thnx for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want to achieve:

```js
const facts = [
  "He was the last Beatle to learn to drive",
  "He was never a vegetarian",
  "He was a choir boy and boy scout",
  "He hated the sound of his own voice"
];

// With one argument (array of facts) it's better :p
function johnLennonFacts(facts) {
  let i = 0;
  const factsModified = [];
  while (i <= facts.length) {
    factsModified.push(facts[i] + '!!');
    i++;
  }

  return factsModified;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use a `while` loop [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) makes this much cleaner.

```js
const facts = [
"He was the last Beatle to learn to drive",
"He was never a vegetarian",
"He was a choir boy and boy scout",
"He hated the sound of his own voice"
];

function append(arr) {
  newArr = arr.map(el => el + ' !!!');
  return newArr;
}

console.log(append(facts));
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I prefer to use a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) when the number of iterations is known from the beginning, and in this case [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) would probably make the most sense as noted in the answer from [@kemotoe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4104766/kemotoe) (but I understand that this is an assignment). There are a few things you need to fix (some have been mentioned in comments and other answers but consolidated here for your reference).

1. Your assignment says that your [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) needs to accept one argument, an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). So you need to have an argument (or parameter) inside the parentheses of your function definition, and then pass your input array to the function when you call it. Something like:

   // function definition
   function johnLennonFacts(arr) {
   // your code
   }

   // pass your "facts" array to the function when you call it
   johnLennonFacts(facts);
2. Your current [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) statement will attempt to log the last 3 elements of your array because you are incrementing `i` before you log the value of your array and 1 is the index of the second element in your array since arrays are zero-indexed (meaning that the first element in your array is at index 0). Then your loop will run into a problem it can't handle when `i` is incremented to 4 but there is no element in `facts` at index 4. The other answers provide some insight into how you can fix your while loop.
3. You need to assign `facts[i] + '!!!'` to an index in the array you plan to return from your function. JavaScript doesn't know that you want it to change `facts[i]` based on this line, it just sees that you are combining it with some other text but not putting it anywhere. The other answers provide some insight into how you can assign your newly combined string to an index in the array you will return from your function.

Just for fun, here is an alternative to the other answers that may give you some additional insight into how functions, loops, and arrays work.

```js
const facts = [
  "He was the last Beatle to learn to drive",
  "He was never a vegetarian",
  "He was a choir boy and boy scout",
  "He hated the sound of his own voice"
];

const exclamation = (arr) => {
  let i = arr.length;
  while (i) {
    i--;
    arr[i] += '!!!';
  }
  
  return arr;
};

const loudfacts = exclamation(facts);
console.log(loudfacts);
/*
[
  "He was the last Beatle to learn to drive!!!",
  "He was never a vegetarian!!!",
  "He was a choir boy and boy scout!!!",
  "He hated the sound of his own voice!!!"
]
*/
```

- `const exclamation = (arr) => {...}` is another way to define a function (called an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions))
- starts by assigning `i = arr.length` so we can loop backwards through the array
- decrements `i` using `i--` before we assign a new string to any array index because we we know that the highest index of an array will be one less than its length since arrays are zero-indexed
- assigns a new string value to each array index using `arr[i] += '!!!'` which is a shortcut way of saying `arr[i] = arr[i] + '!!!'`
- because zero is a ["falsy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value, the while loop exits after the iteration where `i` is decremented to zero
- then we return the modified `arr` from the function
- we call our function and pass the `facts` array to it, assigning the return value to a variable with `let loudfacts = exclamation(facts);`